# Functor $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,-)$, equivalent interpretations (i) group of equivalence classes of short exact sequences, (2) measurement of non-exactnesss

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

All objects in the following live in an abelian category. Consider the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow D\rightarrow 0$.  Apply the Hom-functor $\text{Hom}(A,-)$ where $A$ is also an object in that category. This gives a left exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,B)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,C)\rightarrow\text{Hom}(A,D).$$

Now I  extend the resulting left exact sequence by appending a morphism $\psi:\text{Hom}(A,D)\rightarrow\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$, establishing exactness at $\text{Hom}(A,D)$. I know I can further extend this method to extend further by using the functors $\text{Ext}^n(A,-),n\in\mathbb{N}$ appropriately, but this is not the main point of this question.

I do know the interpretation of $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$ as the group of equivalences classes of short exact sequences $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow E\rightarrow B\rightarrow 0$ with an object $E$ from this category with $A$ being a subobject of $E$ and a surjective morphism from $E$ to $B$ respecting the exactness of the short exact sequence, two such short exact sequences being equivalent if there is an isomorphism between the middle terms (indicated by $E$).

How does the interpretation of $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$ as (i) the group of equivalence classes of short exact sequences of the form $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow E\rightarrow B\rightarrow 0$ relate to the interpretation of $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$, (ii) which says that $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$ measures the non-exactness of the Hom-functor at $\text{Hom}(A,D)$.

I am completely stuck. I do not see the connection between the two views. Clearly the definition of $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$ as a group of equivalence classes of short exact sequences, using the Baer sum as a binary operation seems mathematical rigorous enough. The second view is also a bit sketchy through my description, which also needs clarification.

I am thinking that if $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)=0$, then, as a first illuminating but incomplete  approach to the question, this left exact sequence can be extended to a short exact sequence as well, but even this seems unclear to me; why does the morphism from
$\text{Hom}(A,C)\rightarrow\text{Hom}(A,D)$ become surjective in that case?

Comment: Do you know the construction of the boundary morphism $\operatorname{Hom}(A, D) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1(A, B)$ in terms of the s.e.s. characterization of $\operatorname{Ext}^1$?  The rough idea: if you have a morphism $A \to D$ then you can form a short exact sequence $0 \to B \to A \times_D C \to A \to 0$.  You then just need to prove that that s.e.s. splits (equivalent to the s.e.s. corresponding to 0) if and only if the morphism $A \to D$ factors through $C \to D$.

Comment: Also note that you can have $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B) \not\simeq 0$ but the boundary map $\operatorname{Hom}(A,D)\to\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ being zero; in this case, you'll still have the exactness of the $\operatorname{Hom}$ sequence.  So, that could be a limitation to a strict interpretation of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ measuring the non-exactness.